# Quantifiers uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definition, uniform-continuity, quantifiers

According to this answer:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2582334/1098426

We know $\forall x \ \exists y \ \forall z$ differs from $\forall x \forall z\ \exists y$ insofar as $y$ depends on $x$ versus $y$ depends on $x$ and $z$.

I traditionally translate the definition of uniform continuity on some set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ as $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists d > 0 \ \forall x,y \in A \ : |x-y|<d \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

**Edit:**

The flaw in my original statement is this: $d$ is independent of $x$ and $y$. Including the $\forall$ as first quantifier suggests different $d$ for different $x$ and $y$.

> Could this be written with the third quantifier as the first?
>
> $\forall x,y \in A \ \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists d > 0 \  : |x-y|<d
> > \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$
>
> Typical continuity then would be something like:
>
> $\exists c \in A \ \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists d > 0 \  : |x-c|<d
> > \rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$
>
> Is this a reasonable interpretation?

The revised question:

If the definition of uniformy continuous is $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists d > 0 \ \forall x,y \in A \ : |x-y|<d \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ then does this imply the formal definition of continuity is $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists d > 0 \ \exists c \in A \ : |x-c|<d \rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ as such?

Or, must we state $\exists c \in A$ as first quantifier, mirroring the typical ordinary language definition?

---

Per MSE guidelines, my motive is studying for an exam and trying to prove uniform continuity implies continuity. But, that is just my motive.

Comment: It looks like you've confused some symbols in your last expression of continuity ($c$ is not used and $x,y$ are not quantified). Also note that uniform continuity is defined for a set $A$ whereas continuity is defined at a point. What you should be proving is that uniform continuity on $A$ (i.e. $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta\forall x\forall y\dots$) implies continuity at every point in $A$, i.e. $\forall x\in A,\forall\epsilon\exists\delta\forall y\dots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal definition of "$f$ is continuous on $A$" is
$$
\forall x\in A,\ \forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,\ \forall y\in A,: |x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.\tag{1}
$$
Note that this is just saying "$f$ is continuous at every point $x\in A$," where for fixed $x\in A$, "$f$ is continuous at $x\in A$" means
$$
\forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0,\ \forall y\in A:|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.
$$
When you compare $(1)$ with the definition of "$f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$":
$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0, \forall x,y\in A:|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon,
$$
we see that "$f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$" implies "$f$ is continuous on $A$" in a formal way.

Comment: Thank you. I see I was missing the arbitrary $y$ in $A$ for continuity. For $f$ continuous a fixed single point $x$ in $A$, (your 2nd equation) could we say $\exists x\in A,\ \forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,\ \forall y\in A,: |x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$?

Comment: @isaac: When we want to say $f$ is continuous at $x$, I would leave off the first "$\exists x$" because we already froze $x$ in place and now we are stating what it means for $f$ to be continuous at $x$. This is a definition in terms of numbers $\epsilon,\delta$, and other points $y$ of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I can see how fixing $x$ is a property independent of the definition of continuity, and how adding the quantifier would be unneeded or even confusing. In retrospect, I can make sense of this setting $A=\{x\}$ for your equation $(1)$, but that is a bit of a stretch. I appreciate you taking the time.